# Angular primeng p-table selection of row after grouping data based on row span

Tags: angular, html-table, grouping, selection, primeng

please refer this link https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table/rowgroup rowspan example. when trying to add select feature to the table the row selection is not proper. help me out of this.

here is the link [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hjfmib?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)
just try selecting the rows that are combined.

Thanks in advance.
Happy coding :)

Comment: apply row span according to the number of sub-data.  can't say anything more without your code.

Comment: @AmiLinn added the link for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an attribute **dataKey** which takes a column field value.

Here we need to give dataKay value based on which column we are grouping the data.

here is my updated [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hjfmib?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)